# Bootbox and confirm message

Tags: javascript, bootbox

I use only a basic confirm message, but there is no message displayed.

```
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", "No", "Yes", function(result) {
    alert("test");
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fjd3zzdm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Custom dialog](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-custom-dialog):

```
bootbox.dialog({
    message:"Are you sure?",
    buttons: {
      yes: { //Button Yes
        label: "Yes",
        className: "btn-success",
        callback: function(result) { //Do whatever you want here
            alert("test");   
        }
      },
      no: { //Button No
         label: "No",
        className: "btn-danger",
        callback: function() {}
      }
    }
});
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0bqugt4L/) here! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        $('#form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = this;
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?", function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

This works in `asp.net core`
Name the whole form id as (form)